# SL No generation

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

[image]
There is a master table name as projects master

In another form if I select project-1 sl no need to generate from project master(21819001). after successful 1 record save, if I select same project-1
sl no need to generate like 21819002, for next 21819003, so on.

Again after 3 record save if I select projects-3 sl should generate like 41819001 so on.

I am using Oracle Forms 10g.

Comment: `projects master` is not a valid table name. What is 'SL'?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you might do - create additional table which contains the most recent SL_NO for each project. That number is created with an autonomous transaction function which makes sure that in a multi-user environment you won't get duplicates.

`PROJECTS_MASTER` table and some sample data:

```
SQL> create table projects_master
  2    (project number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> insert into projects_master
  2    select 21819001 from dual union all
  3    select 41819001 from dual;

2 rows created.
```

This table will contain the most recent `SL_NO` for each project

```
SQL> create table projects_sl_no
  2    (project number constraint fk_prsl references projects_master (project),
  3     sl_no   number);

Table created.
```

The function itself; if row for `PAR_PROJECT` exists, it'll update it. Otherwise, it'll create a brand new row in `PROJECTS_SL_NO` table.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_proj_sl_no
  2    (par_project in projects_master.project%type)
  3     return projects_sl_no.sl_no%type
  4  is
  5    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  6    l_sl_no projects_sl_no.sl_no%type;
  7  begin
  8    select b.sl_no + 1
  9      into l_sl_no
 10      from projects_sl_no b
 11      where b.project = par_project
 12      for update of b.sl_no;
 13
 14    update projects_sl_no b
 15      set b.sl_no = l_sl_no
 16      where b.project = par_project;
 17
 18    commit;
 19    return (l_sl_no);
 20  exception
 21    when no_data_found
 22    then
 23      lock table projects_sl_no in exclusive mode;
 24
 25      insert into projects_sl_no (project, sl_no)
 26        values (par_project, par_project);
 27
 28      commit;
 29      return (par_project);
 30  end f_proj_sl_no;
 31  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_proj_sl_no(21819001) sl_no from dual;

     SL_NO
----------
  21819001

SQL> select f_proj_sl_no(21819001) sl_no from dual;

     SL_NO
----------
  21819002

SQL> select f_proj_sl_no(21819001) sl_no from dual;

     SL_NO
----------
  21819003

SQL> select f_proj_sl_no(41819001) sl_no from dual;

     SL_NO
----------
  41819001

SQL> select * from projects_sl_no;

   PROJECT      SL_NO
---------- ----------
  21819001   21819003
  41819001   41819001

SQL>
```

As you use Forms, you could call the `F_PROJ_SL_NO` function in `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD` trigger, `PRE-INSERT`, or even create a *before insert* database trigger if you're inserting into a more complex table than the ones I created for testing purposes. Anyway, that should be a simpler part of the story.