# Auto increment multiple column values from parent id

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, multiple-columns

I have 2 Parent tables like `DEPARTMENT` and `COUNTRY`. In both of these tables, I will have a column saying `LAST_GENERATED_SEQUENCE`. Basically, this will allow me to maintain order of child record creation (order can be re-arranged manually later though)

Now when I insert a record in the child table `EMPLOYEE`, It will insert `DEPARTMENT_SEQUENCE`, and `COUNTRY_SEQUENCE` column values from the above tables by incrementing the value by +1 and the new value will be updated in the parent tables also for next child.

[DEPARTMENT Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdLGh.png)

[COUNTRY Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDNvx.png)

[EMPLOYEE Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnDZf.png)

What is the best way I can achieve this scenario? I will have a large number of records inserted in real life, So I have to take care it does not generate duplicates.

One option I have is to query the value from parent and perform child insert & parent update.
Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't make much sense to me because

- what you really need is master-detail relationship (`department` and `country` masters, `employee` detail with foreign keys establishing referential integrity constraint towards master tables)
- why do you care about order of creation (especially as you can later rearrange those values?). Besides, `MAX + 1` will fail sooner or later in a multi-user environment as two (or more users) will fetch the same value and - if that "sequence" number is supposed to be unique - all other users will suffer from DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
- that's why you should abandon that idea and - if you MUST know the sequence, use exactly that - a **sequence** (database object) which will ensure you have unique values, but not necessarily gapless (who cares?)

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot for your quick response.
I have to run some business logic on that sequence, that is the reason I want to generate the sequence by DEPARTMENT which can not be possible with the database object sequence is not helpful for me.

Comment: Why can't you run business logic on a number retrieved as SEQ_NAME.NEXTVAL, but you can if it is MAX + 1? I don't know, just asking; both will return some number. If you don't care *which* number (could be any), apply that business logic on it.

Comment: Because I have to maintain sequence for each department separately.
HR will start from 1, Sales will start from 1 and so for each department

Comment: Aha. Well, in that case, you might need to create your own logic for maintaining those values (a separate table, an autonomous transaction function that returns next value for each department).

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for making simple things complex in explanation :)

Comment: No problem. Have a look at example I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919485/sl-no-generation/53929895#53929895

Comment: Much helpful @Littlefoot,
Can you please put this in your answer, So I can accept the answer?

Comment: You're welcome. I won't copy that contents over here; you can upvote that another answer, if you want.